# Comparing two sqlite databases using Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new in Python. I am trying to compare two sqlite databases having the same schema. The table structure is also same in both db but the data is different. I want to pickup the rows from both tables from both databases which are not present in either `db1.fdetail` or `db2.fdetail`

`DB1 -`

`Table - fdetail`

```
id    name    key
1     A       k1
2     B       K2
3     C       K3
```

`DB2 -`

`Table - fdetail`

```
id    name    keyid
1     A       k1
2     D       K4
3     E       K5
4     F       K6
```

Expected Output

```
id    name    keyid
1     B       k2
2     C       K3
3     D       K4
4     E       K5
5     F       K6
```

My code is

```
import sqlite3

db1 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\db1.db"
db2 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\db2.db"

tblCmp = "SELECT * FROM fdetail order by id"

conn1 = sqlite3.connect(db1)
conn2 = sqlite3.connect(db2)

cursor1 = conn1.cursor()
result1 = cursor1.execute(tblCmp)
res1 = result1.fetchall()

cursor2 = conn2.cursor()
result2 = cursor2.execute(tblCmp)
res2 = result2.fetchall()
```

So I have got two lists `res1` and `res2`. How can I compare the lists based on the column `Keyid`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both databases are opened in the same connection (which requires [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)), you can do the comparison in SQL:

```
import sqlite3

db1 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\db1.db"
db2 = r"C:\Users\X\Documents\sqlitedb\db2.db"

conn = sqlite3.connect(db1)
conn.execute("ATTACH ? AS db2", [db2])

res1 = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM main.fdetail
                       WHERE keyid NOT IN
                         (SELECT keyid FROM db2.fdetail)
                    """).fetchall()
res2 = conn.execute("""SELECT * FROM db2.fdetail
                       WHERE keyid NOT IN
                         (SELECT keyid FROM main.fdetail)
                    """).fetchall()
```

You can also get a single result by combining the queries with [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound).

Comment: Minor nit, but since the filename in ATTACH is a string expression, not an identifier, could you not pass it using placeholders – compared to using string formatting. Makes little to no difference here, though.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It worked. I didn't understand couple of things. Why is it `main.fdetail` and not `db1.fdetail` in first query

Comment: @IljaEverilä I assumed the database name was not an expression, but testing shows it actually is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use python ‘set’:

```
res1 = set(res1)
res2 = set(res2)
result = res1.symmetric_difference(res2)
```

> The symmetric difference of two sets is the set of elements which are in one of either set, but not in both.

Or you can iterate over both list respectively check for exists or not.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible so that if keyid matches then donot include the row in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your lists into sets and use the available set operations to your intents.